# Mac Parallels - Bridged network

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, parallels

I am new to Apple and my task is to install VMs on a Mac server.

I am trying to install 4 VMs and I want them to have separate IPs and be visible on the network as separate machines. What are my options?

My research shows me that I can use a bridged network, but I have to select an adapter.

I have only two network adapters, does that mean I can only have 2 VMs? And when I configure the 2 VMS, will my actual server have internet connection?

Or does it use the Mac's address?

Answer (score 2):

When you select a network adapter, that means that the VM should expose itself to that network adapter; multiple VMs can expose themselves to the same adapter.

You should choose the adapter your computer is most often hooked up to or (if both are hooked up) whichever one has the network resources you want to talk to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also select "Shared Network" in Parallels Desktop 5/6, which effectively bridges with all host network adapters.